Trying to identify an old black and white blob movie
I'm trying to identify a blob movie I saw in the 1960's.
It's not the Steve McQueen movie nor the Caltiki movie.
I remember in the beginning a guy falls out of a jeep driving fast inside a cave and his arm lands in a pool of mud which is how the blob specimen is picked up.
There is another scene where the blob specimen starts to rise out of a glass case inside a room in a large mansion and one of the characters points a gun at it and it goes back down.
There is another scene near the end which shows the blob has spread across the grounds outside the home and the tanks are all bouncing up and down on top of the blob.  (Although I was terrified watching this as a kid, this scene seems comical now.)  The army tanks eventually fire several bombshells into the blob and there is a scene at the end where the blob is flattened out and smoldering across the grounds.
I originally thought it was Caltiki, the Immortal Monster, but that movie has many differences from what I remember.  For example, I don't remember fire being used to kill the blob.
Any thoughts on what this might be?           

Can't find an exact match but take a look at - https://monstermoviemusic.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/i-was-teenage-blob-look-at-blob-movies.html
